# IntentService on Android run in background

Tags: android, service, background, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I need to have a service in background working on Android.
I made this service:

```
public class ServizioBackgrounds extends IntentService {
    public static int DEFAULT_PORT = 35500;
    private static int BUF_SIZE = 11;
    private static ....
    private static ....

    public ServizioBackgrounds() {
        super("ServizioBackground");
    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        System.out.println("##### Servizio Attivato #####");
        super.onStart(intent, startId); // If I don't use, the onHandleIntent method ins't call
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        System.out.println("### Servizio Terminato ###");

        Intent startService = new Intent("com.perseusgalaxia.interphone_citofono"); // Try.. But this method is never called
        startService.putExtra("AccendiServ", "AccendiServ");
        sendBroadcast(startService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("##### SIAMO DENTRO #####");
        DatagramSocket socketAttesa = null;
            System.out.println("*** IL SERVIZIO E' ATTIVO ***");
        while(true){
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have this BroadcasterReceiver:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("*** Broadcast Ricevuto ***");
        context.startService(new Intent(context,ServizioBackgrounds.class));
    }
}
```

And this is the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".ServizioBackground"
    />
<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.perseusgalaxia.interphone_citofono" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is the part where I start the service for the first time:

```
       Intent startService = new Intent("com.perseusgalaxia.interphone_citofono");
        startService.putExtra("AccendiServ", "AccendiServ");
        sendBroadcast(startService);
```

I call the service in this way just for try.
The problem is that if I start from the app activity the service it start and works fine, but when I close the app the service is close too.
The amazing thing is that if I restart the smartphone the service start in background (without any activity shown etc.) and it works fine. Then (after reboot) if I start the app and close them the service come be closed!

Sorry for my english.
Thank's for answer.

Comment: One problem in this code is that your `onHandleIntent` will never return, you are supposed to create a separate thread inside `onStartCommand` instead of putting your socket code to `onHandleIntent`.

Comment: @pelya IntentService ( this is write on the Android official documentation )  use a thread.

Answer (score 0):

To run your service in the background you need to call `startForeground` from your service.

Here's an example:

```
int serviceId = 101;

NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
b.setContentTitle("Working...")
        .setContentText("I'm working!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

startForeground(serviceId, b.build());
```

Note that if your service runs in the background you must show a notification, so the user is *notified* about your work.